# Doubt about minifigures of LEGO Star Wars on BrickLink not having accessories like weapons

Tags: minifigures, star-wars, bricklink

another user recommend to me in another post [this page](http://www.bricklink.com/) to buy miniatures for my growing collection of minifigures of LEGO Star Wars.

My question regarding the page is simple, there is a large assortment of minifigures of all the years, but why no one includes their accessories? For example, laser sheets or blasters ...

Can the originals be obtained in any way within the page or is there any other method to obtain them?

I've been looking at Amazon, but the prices are very high ... But they do include the minifigures accessories.

Any ideas?

Comment: Bricklink has dedicated categories in the stores' "parts" section for tools, accessories etc. If you know what the minifig needs you will find it there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you've noticed, the [Starwars Minifigs](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogList.asp?catType=M&catString=65) don't come with accessories - this probably makes it easier for the sellers and buyers in terms of sorting: for example the battle packs often came with 3 or 4 different characters along with 2 different weapon styles - there's no definitive "this character has this style of weapon".

The weapons can be found using the [Parts - Minifig, Weapon](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogList.asp?pg=2&catLike=W&sortBy=N&sortAsc=A&catType=P&catID=19) category - there are (at present) 4 guns tagged with `(SW)`, as well as the various different lightsaber hilts (listed as `Weapon Lightsaber Hilt`), various generic weapons (pikes/spears) and the newer "Shooter Mini with [...] Trigger" that is appearing for more play value over authentic weapon styles (another reason why you might want to buy the weapons separately).

In terms of lightsabers, the beams themselves are listed as `Bar 4L (Lightsaber Blade / Wand)` under the [Bars category](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogList.asp?catType=P&catString=46) (there's also Kylo Ren's `Bar 4L / 2L Crossed`).

If you're after more "realistic" weapons, then third party producers may be what you're after. BrickArms do a nice line in [Sci-Fi weapons](http://www.brickarms.com/scifi.php) that include Han's DL-44 and the Imperial issued EL-11, DC-15, DC-15S and D9-AR.

Comment: So there are only these three "official" models of weapons? What is the name given to lightsaber bars? Is there somewhere to buy something more realistic like the "Shooter Mini with [...] Trigger" that you comment?

Comment: Yeah the non-LEGO options are better, so for the lightsaber is better take a original hilt and different colors  of bars dependents of the personage no?

Comment: Yes, but are there different types of beams? I can not look for beams or 4L bars in BrickLinks and get some useful part. I'm using the parts filter...

Answer (score 2):

Since you are asking 'why' accessories are not included in listings for minifigures, I will give you a short and simple answer to directly answer that part of your question.

It is not nearly as efficient to try and have figures with their accessories be listed as it would be for them to be alone. Accessories are different from a minifig's hat, persay, because we do not see a character bald in universe, so the hat is a necessity for their character, but a weapon or accessory does not have that same necessity.

In addition to this, proneness to discrepancies in listings from seller to seller would be much higher when accessories are involved. This is especially true if a figure comes in more than one set, but has different accessories in each set. By keeping accessories and minifigures separate, there will be fewer catalog entries in the database. The goal is always to keep the database as simplistic and easy to use as possible.

I hope that sheds some light on why BL does not list its figures with their accessories (nor does any other third-party-lego-selling website).